# string split '\' in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tokenize

I tried to `split the string` with special character **'\'** but its not working.

```
str = 'c:\images\jhjh.jpg';

result = str.split('\');
```

help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: String should have proper escaping `'c:\\images\\jhjh.jpg'.split('\\');`. One backslash by its own is an escape character, to denote "\" literally you have to escape it itself with one more "\".

Comment: @coolguy but will it result in an array? dun dun dun..

Comment: yeah ofcourse it will be an array

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. However, I am not populating the values, its a auto generated path from input type "file". Also, I have even tried to replace '\' with "\\" and its not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input string should escape `\` and also you should escape `\` in split function argument as well.

This should work

```
str = 'c:\\images\\jhjh.jpg';
result = str.split('\\');
```